# How to return a different object depending on IF in C# (Generics)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dynamic-programming

I have an ASP.NET MVC (Not Core) project where I have run into some problems, and I think finally getting around to learning how to properly use generics could be a solution to my problems.

My case is that I have a SQL connection, that returns data and depending on the result of one field in the SQL, I want to use two different models. The models have a lot of properties in common so I thought the best practice would be to create a method that selects which of the models to create, fill in the differences, return the model and then continue to fill in the "common" properties.

I have tried to read a little on Generics but I am quite new to this so I haven't made any big strides.

My code example looks like this:

```
public ResultVM MainClass()
{
    var resultData = new ResultVM();

    // ... SQL returns data

    while (reader.Read())
    {
        resultData.Add(reader);
    }

    return resultData;
}

public object CreateObject(SqlDataReader indata)
{

    if((indata["Associate"].ToString()) == "0")
    {
        var individual = new Individual();
    }
    else
    {
        var group = new Group();
    }

    return object;
}
```

How can I dynamically (depending on the value of `Associate` field) create an individual or a group?

Comment: Make things simple, use two different methods[`CreateAssociateObject()` and `CreateGroupObject()`] and avoid unwanted casting

Comment: That's the absolutely best way of doing things? Since they have a lot of properties in common that would mean I would repeat myself a lot.

Comment: Then why don't you create an `Interface` with those common things?

Comment: yes @sujithkarivelil is right create Interface and return reference of it or create base class for return it

Comment: If two models can be sub class of a meaningful base class, you can create a base class and move the common properties to there. But I smell some wrong design decisions here. Can you explain what you are trying to do? Why do you have some requirement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest working directly with `System.Type` in your case. Here can be multiple more elegant solutions of your problem, depending of what you actually need:

1. `indata.GetFieldType(int ordinal)` will return the .NET type of your field
2. [Serialize data with type handling](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializeTypeNameHandling.htm), then you can simply get type after non generic deserialization. For example:

   ```
   var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(dataJson);
   ```

`result` will have Type of your actual object type. You can check it writing result.GetType() and create an object of this type. For more advanced use see `Activator.CreateInstance(...)`

3. For the most cases using interface is the best way:

   ```
   interface ISomething
   {
       // ...
   }

   class Individual : ISomething
   {
       // ...
   }

   class Group : ISomething
   {
       // ...
   }
   ```

Then you cat build your non generic method this way:

```
public ISomething CreateObject(SqlDataReader indata) 
{
    if((indata["Associate"].ToString()) == "0")
        return new Individual();
    else
        return new Group();
}
```

Your generic object creation may look something like this:

```
public T CreateObject<T>(SqlDataReader indata) 
{
    var o = new T();
    return o;
}
```

Where `T` is type, that you pass outside this method: `CreateObject<YourType>(indata)`
`T` can be any Type you want including Interfaces. Also working with generics you may want check types by using `is` keyword, but I recommend using interfaces and avoid `is` checks at all.
Example:

```
if(yourObject is YourType)
{
    (yourObject as YourType).SomeSpecificToYourTypeMethod();
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What about implementing an interface with all the common properties?

Something like

```
interface IInterface
{
    string CommonProperty1 { get; set; }
    string CommonProperty2 { get; set; }
}

class Individual : IInterface
{
    // ...
}

class Group : IInterface
{
    // ...
}

public IInterface CreateObject(SqlDataReader indata)
{
    if((indata["Associate"].ToString()) == "0")
    {
        var individual = new Individual();
        // ...  
        return individual;
    }
    else
    {
        var group = new Group();
        // ...
        return group;
    }
}
```

Comment: If they have common properties, I would argue a base class instead of an interface would be better suited.